# understanding remote login to linux server and to sqlplus via ssh

Tags: server, ssh

OS ubuntu 20.04

So for my school work, I am connecting to a Linux server using my school username and password.

example in terminal:

> ssh me@name-of-remote_host

> me@name-of-remote_host 's password: ....

> ' [me@remote_host~]: sqlplus

this will prompt me to enter:

> Enter user-name:

> Enter password:

If I want to change the second (sqlplus) password how I would do that assuming that I have the privilege to do so?

Also, can someone explain to me or reference some resources to understand how all this been created from the school end point? Is it just creating Linux server with users and for sqlplus same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your SQL*Plus password after logging into the database using the `password` command. SQL*Plus will prompt your for the current password, then ask for the new one twice.

As for the second question, it *looks like* a standard Ubuntu Server installation with OpenSSH and SQL*Plus installed. You can build something similar in a VM using an Ubuntu Server .iso file, and choosing to install OpenSSH as part of the installation process. The SQL*Plus installation is a little more complicated, but there are plenty of How To's online for this process. If you have questions during any of these installations, feel free to create a new question

Comment: I do have VM with both ubuntu and Centos 7 though I am not sure  how to tell if they are desktop or server? Does it matter if they either one? And so to clarify  the process goes like this build VM with ubuntu server >> install openSSH inside the VM >> install SQLplus too >> create user(s) that have access to the server? and create user(s) for sql?

Comment: If you have an Ubuntu Desktop VM (which has a GUI) then you do not need to make a Server VM (which has no GUI). You *can*, of course, but the software you need is the very same. As for the process you outlined, those steps will certainly accomplish your goal 